# Handling TypeLoadException while reading AppSettings.json in startup

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am working on ASP.NET core application where I implementing functionality which will read values from appsetting.json

For this, I am following this tutorial - http://benjii.me/2016/04/new-configuration-appsettings-mvc6-web-config-gone/

From this tutorial, I am following automatic bind all app settings in following way-

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
}
```

On this particular line - `services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));`, I am getting below exception-

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

**Project.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics":"1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I am not able to figure out what I am missing here. Can some one please point I am missing here?

My environment is VS2015 Professional update3 and a Windows 7 machine.

Thanks & Regards

Vishal

Comment: Show your `project.json`

Comment: haim770 added project.json

Answer (score 0):

Add the following package in your project.json

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
```

This package contains the OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions class wich has the extension method `IServiceCollection Configure<TOptions>`